# about win32 standalone:tracking a browser?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a standalone using c++.In my standalone I want it to track user's clicks,I mean which link does he/she clicks.I am trying to count how much time  he/she uses a perticular site,like pageaddict(a firefox extension).
So any support..?

Comment: Why not creating a browser plugin? Is it supposed to be a spyware?

Comment: No dude!! I just want to get to know the time spend on a perticular site not the credentials.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a Firefox extension, you should be using JavaScript. In C++, you might make a sniffer, which could tell you from what site the packets you receive are from. But that would require quite a lot of knowledge and of time.

Comment: Yes.But if i am using borland,vcl framework will this be more easy?
Ok tell me is it possible to check which browser is opened by user in vcl or c++?

Comment: Using this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , you can get all launched process, and then you can search for one called firefox.exe ou ie.exe (assuming windows).